# specify the first day of a 3 months period (to plot a line plot)

Tags: r

my data look like

```
> keep_long_format
          Date              Injury.Cause  n
1   2019-03-25         Falls from height  1
2   2019-03-25     Falls on level ground  3
3   2019-03-25    Road traffic accidents  3
4   2019-03-26    Road traffic accidents  5
5   2019-03-27     Falls on level ground  3
6   2019-03-27    Road traffic accidents  3
7   2019-03-28     Falls on level ground  2
8   2019-03-28    Road traffic accidents  3
9   2019-03-29     Falls on level ground  4
10  2019-03-29    Road traffic accidents  9
11  2019-03-30         Falls from height  2
12  2019-03-30     Falls on level ground  2
13  2019-03-30    Road traffic accidents  7
14  2019-03-31     Falls on level ground  1
15  2019-03-31    Road traffic accidents  1
16  2019-04-01     Falls on level ground  3
17  2019-04-02 Assaults related injuries  1
18  2019-04-02     Falls on level ground  1
19  2019-04-02    Road traffic accidents  2
20  2019-04-03         Falls from height  2
21  2019-04-03    Road traffic accidents  4
22  2019-04-04         Falls from height  2
23  2019-04-04     Falls on level ground  2
24  2019-04-04    Road traffic accidents  6
```

I want to plot these data on line plot and show data of each three months.

This is what I did

```
keep_long_format <- keep_long_format %>% mutate(Trimonthly = round_date(Date, unit = "3 months" )) 



Pivot.Trimonthly <- keep_long_format %>%
  group_by(Trimonthly, Injury.Cause ) %>%
  summarise(Trimonthly.sum = sum(n))
```

the problem is that cases during the 5 days before 2019-4-1 are considered as a separate 3 months and looks very low (of course as it reflects 5 days compared to the three months data points on the plot)

How can I make the 3 months start from 2019-3-25 to 2019-6-24 (and then, the next 3 months start from 2019-6-25 ...etc)

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, create a sequence containing the cutoff dates every 3 months. Then, use `findInterval` to see where each date lies in the sequence vector. For example:

```
date_seq <- seq(as.Date("2019-3-25"), as.Date("2020-3-25"), by = "3 months")

df <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date("2019-3-25"), as.Date("2020-04-01"), by = "1 day")
)

df$trimonth <- findInterval(df$date, date_seq)
```

**Output**

```
          date trimonth
1   2019-03-25        1
2   2019-03-26        1
3   2019-03-27        1
4   2019-03-28        1
5   2019-03-29        1
...
90  2019-06-22        1
91  2019-06-23        1
92  2019-06-24        1
93  2019-06-25        2
94  2019-06-26        2
95  2019-06-27        2
96  2019-06-28        2
...
183 2019-09-23        2
184 2019-09-24        2
185 2019-09-25        3
186 2019-09-26        3
...
```

If you want to use starting dates in your plot, you can reference them as:

```
date_seq[df$trimonth]

[1] "2019-03-25" "2019-03-25" "2019-03-25" "2019-03-25"
...
```